# Why does Rails not recognize a *.js.coffee template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am following the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1". There is a section on using Ajax, for getting a "shopping cart" model to update without a page reload.

Here is the controller `app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb`:

```rb
def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    session[:counter] = 0

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_url }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The book says that the function of `respond_to` in the above function will cause the `create.js.coffee` template to be executed.

Here is `app/views/line_items/create.js.coffee`:

```coffee
cart = document.getElementById("cart")
cart.innerHTML = "<%= j render(@cart) %>"
```

Finally, the button to add an item to the cart is defined like this :

```html
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
```

The book says that the `remote: true` part will cause the page to not reload.

With the file named `create.js.coffee`, the cart does not update at all like it should. However, when I rename the file to be `create.js.erb`, I do see the cart asynchronously refresh without a page reload. What gives?

The log message I get when the file is named `create.js.coffee` is `No template found for LineItemsController#create, rendering head :no_content`.

When the file is named `create.js.erb`, I see that the template is found and rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the `coffee-rails` gem. I'm not sure why I didn't have this already - I am using Rails 6.0.1.

Comment: Rails no longer ships with Coffeescript by default. Its really fallen out of vogue since ES6 has most of the features that distinguished CS without all the problems related to writing in another language that compiles to JS. There is ongoing work to remove coffescript from all the guides. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37742